# How to multiply values in an asymmetric encryption without decrypting

Tags: math, cryptography, rsa

I was going through some questions and one of the questions made me confused on which asymmetric encryption to be using.

**The question is as follows.**

A student creates a service for multiplication. It takes two numbers and then returns the result of the multiplication. The student claims that you can send the numbers to be multiplied encrypted by a suitable algorithm and the service would send you a product encrypted as well.

In other words you would send them E(x1) and E(x2) and the value you get from the service would be E(x1*x2). You can decrypt this value to get the product. The students service would have no idea on what numbers you had multiplied.

*I'm leaning towards RSA. However RSA would require the receiving party to decrypt the values before multiplying them, but that is not to be done.*

Comment: The keyword is [homomorphic encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphic_encryption)

Comment: RSA is multiplicative. If `E` is the unpadded RSA exponentiation primitive (often described as RSA encryption) then E(x1)*E(x2) = E(x1*x2) mod n. As long as x1*x2 < n you can decrypt the result to get x1*x2. The receiving party (the service) need not decrypt anything, all they do is multiply mod n.

Comment: Thank You both those answers were helpful